# In the integral domain $D = \{r+s \sqrt{17}: r,s \in\Bbb Z\}$, which element is irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

In the integral domain $D = \{r + s \sqrt{17} | r,s \in\Bbb Z\}$, which is irreducible?

$3 - \sqrt{17}$

$9 - 2\sqrt{17}$

$7 + \sqrt{17}$

$13 + \sqrt{17}$

I got all of them are irreducible, if you try to make it, for example, $3 - \sqrt{17} = (a + b \sqrt {17}) (c + d \sqrt{17})$, where $a, b,c,d\in\Bbb Z$  are integers, you will see $a = b = 0 $ or $c = d = 0$. and this apply to all the above four.

Comment: How does one see that? If you're asking for a check of your work, you should post it all, if you're asking for something else, you should clarify.

Comment: I'm looking for any solutions. could you solve it?

Comment: It's probable that a no-holds-barred solution would be using material you've never seen. If you can post what you've already tried it will give me (and everyone else) a sense of where you are, academically, so that we can post solutions which will actually make sense to you. For example, my first instinct is to look at ideal norms in the ring $\Bbb Z\left[{1+\sqrt{17}\over 2}\right]$, and to use quadratic reciprocity, on a lot of these, which uses a lot of machinery, making it less likely you've seen it. But no one will want to guess and write up an answer only to find it's useless to the op.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not all irreducible. For example, we have
$$
13+\sqrt{17}=(6-\sqrt{17})(5+\sqrt{17}).
$$
The norm of $13+\sqrt{17}$ is $152=8\cdot 19$, and $N(6-\sqrt{17})=19$, $N(5+\sqrt{17})=8$.